# Subset and loop calculation over each column in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a dataframe of values for 50 IDs repeated over 10 iterations. I would like to subset by ID and then perform calculations, and repeat that for each column from `x1` to `x5`. I used a for-loop but it is very inefficient (my actual dataset has a lot more IDs).

Here are the calculations I would like to perform. I've had varying success with the conversion to dplyr:

1. First calculation, gives me the correct value for `x1`, but need to repeat for each column from `x1` to `x5`.

```
V1.x1 <- preds.df %>%
  split(.$ID) %>%
  sapply(function(ID) {
    (ID$x1 - mean(ID$x1))^2 # for X1 only
  }) %>%
  mean()
```

2. A different calculation that involves subtracting from a corresponding value in another df `data.pop`. My dplyr attempt is wrong even for just `x1`:

```
## This is what I want to achieve, which I implemented using for-loop: 
# df for for-loop
Bsq.perID <- data.frame(matrix(NA, 
                               nrow = nrow(data.pop),     # 50 observations
                               ncol = 5)                  # 5 models
                        
# For-loop:
for (ids in 1:nrow(data.pop)){
  current.ID <- preds.df[preds.df$ID == ids, ]  # get current ID over all 10 iterations
  
  for (i in 1:5){
    Bsq.perID[ids, i] <- (mean(current.ID[, i]) - data.pop[ids, "real.val"])^2 
  }
  
}
Bsq.values <- colMeans(Bsq.perID)

## My wrong dplyr attempt of the above:
B1.x1 <- preds.df %>%
  split(.$ID) %>%
  sapply(function(ID) {
    (mean(ID$x1) - data.pop$real.val)^2 
  }) %>%
  mean()
```

The structure of `preds.df` looks like this:

```
head(preds.df)
```

```
         x1          x2        x3        x4        x5 iteration          ID
1 20.005984  6.78242996  3.526411 21.463892  8.792720         1           1
2  2.890490  7.28232755 18.670470  6.717213 19.830930         1           2
3  4.868658 24.88117301  1.883913  3.897779 14.371414         1           3
4  6.495532  5.79591685  7.745554 20.153269  7.935672         1           4
5 19.297779  0.05068784 21.744816 14.957751 14.232126         1           5
6  7.090456 22.06322779  8.388263 10.672151  9.921884         1           6
```

```
tail(preds.df)
```

```
           x1         x2         x3        x4        x5 iteration          ID
495 16.306927  2.8873609  9.7764755 23.798867 10.246443        10          45
496  4.767296 23.2086303  8.8394391  7.806442 24.898483        10          46
497 19.966301 13.7151699 10.2483011 15.199162  9.658736        10          47
498 18.134534 22.1658901  5.6481757 18.501411 23.787457        10          48
499  7.877636  7.2356274  8.2862336  3.790823 11.610848        10          49
500  8.554774  0.9199501  0.9650191 17.155611  1.158619        10          50
```

Comment: Can you post the data you're using?

Comment: Yes please find it here https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ahs_wcfc575qWn3A0LXtFQld7YKuoqA3?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would approach it like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(rio)
preds.df <- import("~/Downloads/preds.df.csv")
data.pop <- import("~/Downloads/data.pop.csv")
## added a row because data.pop is only 49 rows in the data you sent
data.pop <- bind_rows(data.pop, data.pop[1,])
```

You could use `dplyr` with `mutate()` to do this:

```
dat1 <- preds.df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(across(x1:x5, function(x)(x-mean(x))^2))
```

Then, for the second part you could merge the data

```
data.pop <- data.pop %>% 
  mutate(ID = 1:n())

dat2 <- dat1 %>% left_join(data.pop)
```

Next, summarise on ID to calculate the mean of `x1` to `x5`  within `ID`, then from each one, you can subtract `real.val` and square.

```
dat2 <- dat2 %>% 
  select(c(ID, x1:x5, real.val)) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(across(x1:x5, function(x)(x-real.val)^2)) %>% 
  summarise_all(mean) %>% 
  select(-real.val)
```

Comment: Part 1 worked. Thanks! As for the second one, removing `summarise_all(mean)` I get answers that are close but not correct still. My goal is, for each column, take the mean of x for each ID across the iterations, then subtract that mean from that ID's real.val and square it. Repeat for all IDs, all 5 columns. Then use `colMeans()` to return 5 values at the end. Basically I am calculating Bias^2 for each model here.

Comment: Upon further inspection, I realised it is doing things correctly up till `summarise_all(mean)`, the error lies in subtracting the corresponding ID's `real.val` from each value.

Comment: @fluent If you swap the placement of the summarise_all and mutate statements that should do it.  What was happening above was that it was getting the mean and then subtracting `real.val` from the mean and squaring rather than the other way around.